# Get Request with Axios to Express return HTML instead of JSON - Suspecting an issue with NGINX reverse proxy set up

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy

I am having an issue when I GET request data from my react.js app to my Express.js backend, I am getting HTML garbage back instead of what my backend is supposed to return. Upon debugging and researching, I found out that the reason for that is because my GET route "/order/getTimeSlots" actually returns HTML content that is displayed when I go to mywebsite.com/order/getTimeSlots instead of my backend. I have set up proxy in my development environment and it works, however, it does not work in production. I am using nginx to serve my react app and here is my nginx config

```
    server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/mywebsite.com;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;



    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            try_files $uri /index.html;
    }



    location /ordersubmit {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080; #this is where my backend app is running on
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;


    }

    location /order/getTimeSlots {
    proxy_pass https://localhost:8080;  #this is where my backend app is running on
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;


    }
    }
```

When trying curl on localhost:8080/getTimeSlots from my server console, I am getting the correct response.

I know there is a problem with my reverse proxy set up, but I cannot figure out what the issue is, so I was wondering if someone here can help

Thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue myself, I realized that I was adding those locations under the server that listens to port 80, but since I am using https, I was supposed to use port 443